# removing object pointer from stl list

Tags: c++, stl

Consider the following code, which is causing an access violation:

```
for(std::list<ProjectileNode*>::iterator it = m_Projectiles.begin(); it!=m_Projectiles.end(); it++)
{
    if(!(*it)->isActive()) //isActive returns a bool
    {
        m_Projectiles.remove((*it));
    }
}
```

`if(!(*it)->isActive())` is causing the exception.

I'm new to using lists, and could use some help. The pointed-to objects are managed elsewhere so I don't want them destroyed, only removed from the list, without causing this exception

Comment: Have you checker that the pointer is valid?

Comment: the removal seems to work just fine, but the list has had an entry removed, it crashes

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you already have an iterator to the element you want to remove from the list, you shouldn't use `remove()`, as this will search for the element again. Instead, use `erase()`, which also returns an iterator pointing after the erased element.

This leads to the classic "erase some elements" loop which looks like this:

```
for(std::list<ProjectileNode*>::iterator it = m_Projectiles.begin(); it != m_Projectiles.end(); /*increment in body*/)
{
    if(!(*it)->isActive()) //isActive returns a bool
    {
        it = m_Projectiles.erase(it);
    }
    else
    {
        ++it;
    }
}
```

Of course, @juanchopanza's answer shows how to do this using standard algorithms without using loops altogether.

Comment: Thanks. I chose this as I don;t have to define functions elsewhere for it to work, but I really wish I could mark several answers as accepted. Upvotes and thanks for everyone!

Answer (score 7):

Your best bet would be to use [`std::list::remove_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/remove) with a suitable predicate:

```
bool pred(const ProjectileNode* p) { return !p->isActive(); }

m_Projectiles.remove_if(pred);
```

Or, in C++11,

```
m_Projectiles.remove_if([](const ProjectileNode* p)
                        { return !p->isActive(); });
```

Comment: Is this C++11? +1; very cute.

Comment: @Bathsheba I *think* it is also C++03.

Comment: @juanchopanza I can confirm that it works in C++03: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f293eacc0774cddb.

Comment: @rightfold Thanks. I certainly used it before, I just wasn't 100% sure it wasn't a compiler extension.

Comment: I really like how concise this is, though vs2010 doesn't seem to like it very much. I assume the predicate function must be declared elsewhere?

Comment: @IanYoung define it outside of any functions.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks. I don;t really have a suitable place to define it in my code base as yet, but I'll remember it in future.

Comment: @IanYoung do you need this in many places? If not, you can just palce the function in an anonymous namespace in the file it is used.

Answer (score 3):

This is classic *iterator invalidation* I'm afraid.

`m_Projectiles.remove((*it));` *invalidates* `it`. The `it++` execution done by the `for` loop will give you *undefined behaviour*. Then you're in a bad place indeed.

A crude solution would be to use

```
if (!(*it)->isActive()){
    std::list<ProjectileNode*>::iterator new_it = it;
    ++new_it; /*I prefer this to new_it++*/
    m_Projectiles.remove((*it));
    it = new_it;
} else {
   ++it;
}
```

as the body of your `if` statement **and remove** the `it++` in your `for` loop. Refactor to taste in production code. What I'm doing here is advancing the iterator to a safe node before deleting the one I no longer need.